# Does the variance have linearity property??

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance

Suppose we have a variance of $c_i$ as $Var(c_i)$ for $i = 1, \dots ,k$.

We also have $k$ scalars $a_1, \dots, a_k$.

Then what is the variance of the linear combination $C = \sum_i^k a_i \cdot c_i$??

Let's denote it by $Var(C)$, then is it possible to define $Var(C)$ by using $Var(c_i)$ and $a_i$??
If so, how do we do it?

Comment: No, it is not. You can have a look at the Wikipedia page to see that you have to square the scalars, assuming you have independence. Otherwise terms called "covariances" appear.

Comment: $Var(C) = (\sum_{i=1}^k |a_i|^2 \cdot Var(c_i))^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is this true? (Assuming independence)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming independence (as you did in the comment) it holds in fact that
$$Var(\sum_i a_i c_i) = \sum_i a_i^2 Var(c_i). $$
I am not quite sure, where your power $0.5$ comes from but it is not correct, anyway. In general, you have for any sum of type $\sum_i a_i c_i$, such that the variance of all $c_i$ exists, the formula
$$Var(\sum_i a_i c_i) = \sum_i a_i^2 Var(c_i) + 2\sum_{i\neq j} a_i a_j Cov(c_i,c_j)$$, which follows directly from the binomial formula for $\left(\sum_i a_i c_i\right)^2$ (and can also be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_variables))